# Esp32 Controlar 2 Servo via Wifi no funciona correctamente ifelse en numeros 50,55,100,105,150,155

Tags: arduino, esp32

tengo este codigo para controlar un modlulo esp32 por via wifi pero en grados como 50, 55,100,105,150,155 el ingresa a la funcion movimientoEntreAngulos() que esta creada para ejecutarse una vez y ejecuta en orden secuencial los condicionales de dicha funcion cosas que es un error porque si el angulo anterior es iugal al enviado por el usuario deberia no hacer nada, si el angulo es menor ingresa a uno de los condicionales al igual que si es mayor pero esto funciona con todos los demas angulos menos con estos que mencione 50, 55,100,105,150,155 que ejecuta el prime condicional despues ejecuta el siguiente y no deberia ser asi.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>

const char* ssid = "prueba";
const char* password = "wifiprueba";

int backupAngulo ;
int nuevoAngulo ;
int tiempo=150;

WiFiServer server(80);

#define ledRojo 25
int  pinServo = 33;
int pinServoZoom=32;

Servo myServo;
Servo ServoZoom;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(ledRojo, OUTPUT);

  myServo.attach(pinServo, 500, 2500);
  ServoZoom.attach(pinServoZoom, 500, 2500);

  connectWiFi();
  backupAngulo=0; 
  nuevoAngulo =0;
  myServo.write(backupAngulo);
  ServoZoom.write(90);
}
/***************************************************
* Connecting to a WiFi network
****************************************************/
void connectWiFi(void)
{
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Conectando a ...");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("Buscando Wifi :");
    digitalWrite(ledRojo, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledRojo, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

/***************************************************
* Zoom
****************************************************/
void ManejoDeZoom(int x) {

  digitalWrite(ledRojo, HIGH);
  if (x == 1) {
    ServoZoom.write(70); 
    delay(300); 
    ServoZoom.write(90)
  } else if (x == 2) { 
    ServoZoom.write(120);
    delay(300);
    ServoZoom.write(90);
  }
  digitalWrite(ledRojo, LOW);
}

/***************************************************
* Paneos
****************************************************/
void paneosGeneral(int x) {
  digitalWrite(ledRojo, HIGH);
  if (x == 1) { 
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
      myServo.write(i);
      delay(tiempo);
    }
  } else if (x == 2) { 
  
    for (size_t i = 180; i >= 0; i--) {
      myServo.write(i);
      delay(tiempo);
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(ledRojo, LOW);
}
/***************************************************
* Angulos
****************************************************/
void movimientoEntreAngulos(int anguloAntiguo, int anguloNuevo) {

  digitalWrite(ledRojo, HIGH);

  Serial.println("inicio funcion ");
 if (anguloAntiguo == anguloNuevo) {
  Serial.println("Los angulops son iguales");

 }else if (anguloAntiguo < anguloNuevo){
  Serial.println("Movimendo de menor a mayor ");

  for (size_t i = anguloAntiguo; i <= anguloNuevo; i ++) {
    myServo.write(i);
    delay(tiempo);
    }   
    backupAngulo=anguloNuevo;
    anguloNuevo=0; 
    Serial.println("fin movimiento ");
  }else if(anguloAntiguo > anguloNuevo){

    Serial.println("Movimendo de Mayor a Menor ");
    for (size_t i = anguloAntiguo; i >= anguloNuevo; i --) {
    myServo.write(i);
    delay(tiempo);
    }
    backupAngulo=anguloNuevo;
    anguloNuevo=0;
    Serial.println("fin movimeinto ");
  }
  Serial.println("fin de función ");
  digitalWrite(ledRojo, LOW);
}
void loop() {
    ServoZoom.write(90);
    WiFiClient client = server.available();

    if (client) {
        String currentLine = "";
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                if (c == '\n') {
                    if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
                        // Respuesta HTTP
                        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                        client.println("Content-type:text/html");
                        client.println();
                        // Contenido HTML
                        client.print("<html><body>");
                        client.print("<h1>Bienvenido Ingeniero Eliasib</h1></br>");
                        client.print("<h1>Software control camara 1</h1></br>");
                        client.print("</br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/ZIN\"><h1> ZOOM Menos</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/ZOUT\"><h1> ZOOM Mas</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/180\"><h1> 180 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/175\"><h1> 175 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/170\"><h1> 170 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/165\"><h1> 165 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/160\"><h1> 160 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/155\"><h1> 155 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/150\"><h1> 150 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/145\"><h1> 145 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/140\"><h1> 140 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/135\"><h1> 135 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/130\"><h1> 130 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/125\"><h1> 125 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/120\"><h1> 120 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/115\"><h1> 115 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/110\"><h1> 110 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/105\"><h1> 105 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/100\"><h1> 100 Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/95 \"><h1> 95  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/90 \"><h1> 90  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/85 \"><h1> 85  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/80 \"><h1> 80  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/75 \"><h1> 75  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/70 \"><h1> 70  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/65 \"><h1> 65  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/60 \"><h1> 60  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/55 \"><h1> 55  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/50 \"><h1> 50  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/45 \"><h1> 45  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/40 \"><h1> 40  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/35 \"><h1> 35  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/30 \"><h1> 30  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/25 \"><h1> 25  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/20 \"><h1> 20  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/15 \"><h1> 15  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/10 \"><h1> 10  Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("<a href=\"/5  \"><h1> 5   Grados</h1></a></br>");
                        client.print("</body></html>");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        currentLine = "";
                    }
                } else if (c != '\r') {
                    currentLine += c;
                }

                // Manejo de comandos
                if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /ZOUT")) { ManejoDeZoom(1); }
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /ZIN")) { ManejoDeZoom(2);} 
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /PANEO1")) { paneosGeneral(1); } 
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /PANEO2")) {  paneosGeneral(2); }
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /5")) { nuevoAngulo  = 5;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /10")) { nuevoAngulo = 10;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /15")) { nuevoAngulo = 15;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /20")) { nuevoAngulo = 20;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /25")) { nuevoAngulo = 25;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /30")) { nuevoAngulo = 30;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /35")) { nuevoAngulo = 35;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /40")) { nuevoAngulo = 40;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /45")) { nuevoAngulo = 45;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /50")) { nuevoAngulo = 50;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /55")) { nuevoAngulo = 55;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /60")) { nuevoAngulo = 60;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /65")) { nuevoAngulo = 65;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /70")) { nuevoAngulo = 70;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /75")) { nuevoAngulo = 75;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /80")) { nuevoAngulo = 80;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /85")) { nuevoAngulo = 85;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /90")) { nuevoAngulo = 90;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /95")) { nuevoAngulo = 95;   movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /100")) { nuevoAngulo = 100 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /105")) { nuevoAngulo = 105 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /110")) { nuevoAngulo = 110 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /115")) { nuevoAngulo = 115 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /120")) { nuevoAngulo = 120 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /125")) { nuevoAngulo = 125 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /130")) { nuevoAngulo = 130 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /135")) { nuevoAngulo = 135 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /140")) { nuevoAngulo = 140 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /145")) { nuevoAngulo = 145 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /150")) { nuevoAngulo = 150 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /155")) { nuevoAngulo = 155 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /160")) { nuevoAngulo = 160 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /165")) { nuevoAngulo = 165 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /170")) { nuevoAngulo = 170 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}
                else if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /175")) { nuevoAngulo = 175 ;    movimientoEntreAngulos(backupAngulo, nuevoAngulo) ;}

        
            }
        }
        client.stop();
    }
}
```